# How do you add lens profiles to Adobe Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, sigma

I just received my Sigma 18-35 and love it. I use Lightroom for editing and according to Adobe, the Sigma 18-35 f 1.8 is supported. When  I go to lens correction, I don't see the lens available.

Do you have to manually add the Lens profile? If so how do you go about doing this? I can't find anything when I search around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, the photos have to be shot in RAW. I was editing trying to edit via jpg that was shot on the 70d with the sigma 18-35. Thanks for you help @ElendilTheTall

Answer (score 3):

You can either wait for Adobe to add it in an update, or if you can't wait you can download the **Lens Profile Downloader**. If the lens profile isn't available yet you can make your own with the **Lens Profile Creator**. Both are available to download from Adobe [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/digital-negative.html#resources).

Comment: Adobe says it is supported http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/lens-profile-support-lightroom-4.html 

however when I go to Lightroom 5.5, lens profiles, I only see sigma DC 4.5mm, 18-200, 8mm, 12-24 and the 15mm

Comment: What brand of camera are you using? Also, have you tried using the tools I linked to in any case?

Comment: Yes I tried the lens profile downloader, it has the same profiles as I stated in the previous comment. I'm shooting with a Canon 70d.

Comment: I have the 18-35 1.8 in Lightroom 5.5 (Camera Raw 8.5), but not in the Downloader. Weird. Is your version of Lightroom fully up-to-date?

Comment: I just installed LR 5.5 from Creative Cloud. I went in and checked for a software update and it said I am all up to date. I'm pretty sure I'm looking in the correct location as well. Under develop / lens corrections / profile... enable profile corrections Make: Sigma Model: lenses stated above

Comment: I'm on pc as well, not sure if that matters

Answer (score 2):

There is a readme.txt at both

```
C:\ProgramData\Adobe\CameraRaw\LensProfiles\1.0\ThirdParty
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Lightroom Classic\Resources\LensProfiles\1.0\ThirdParty
```

that reads

```
Install third-party (non-Adobe) lens profiles here.
```

By default, `.lcp` files are saved to

```
C:\Users\your-user-name\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CameraRaw\LensProfiles\1.0
```

I left my original file in AppData and then copied that file to both these locations. I didn't investigate which location Lightroom is dependant upon, but Adobe keeps identical lens profile directories on my computer; adding to their file clutter worked for me.